# SELECT en una BBDD e INSERT en otra

Tags: python, base-de-datos, postgresql, tkinter

Estoy creando un programita en el cual cogo los datos de una base de datos y los vuelco en otra diferente. He estado mirando varios videos con SELECT e INSERT INTO en python y psycopg2.

Es basicamente un Tkinter con un boton que le das a sync_bb() y traspasa los datos de una a otra.
Una base de datos es adverp y la otra sinf_tickets

```
def sync_bbdd():
    ##BBDD ADV
    connadv = psycopg2.connect(
        host="localhost",
        database = "adverp",
        user = "postgresl",
        password = "1234",
        port = "5432",
    )
    cadv = connadv.cursor()
    ##BBDD TICKET
    connticket = psycopg2.connect(
        host="localhost",
        database = "sinf_tickets",
        user = "postgresl",
        password = "1234",
        port = "5432",
    )
    cticket = connticket.cursor()  

    ##CONSULTA EN BBDD ADVERP
    cadv.execute('''select sat.vlstintervencion_pendientes.codincidencia,T26."tecnicoasignado",sat.vlstintervencion_pendientes.presupuesto,T26."codincidenciaestado",T26."codincidenciasubestado",T26."fecha",T26."hora",T27."referencia",T26."modelo",T26."codcliente",T28."razon",T29."poblacion",T26."codzonatecnica",T30."descripcion",T26."problema", sat.vlstintervencion_pendientes.codtecnico, sat.vlstintervencion_pendientes.fechainicio, sat.vlstintervencion_pendientes.horainicio, T28.razon, sat.vlstintervencion_pendientes.codincidencia from sat.vlstintervencion_pendientes left join sat.vlstincidencia as T26 on sat.vlstintervencion_pendientes.cod_empresa=T26.cod_empresa and sat.vlstintervencion_pendientes.codincidencia=T26.codigo  left join sat.equipo as T27 on T26.codequipo=T27.codigo  left join gen.vlstcliente as T28 on T26.codcliente=T28.codigo  left join gen.direccion as T29 on T26.coddireccion=T29.codigo  left join sat.zonatecnica as T30 on T26.codzonatecnica=T30.codigo  where (sat.vlstintervencion_pendientes.cod_empresa='FM4' or sat.vlstintervencion_pendientes.cod_empresa is null ) and (sat.vlstintervencion_pendientes.presupuesto is null and replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(upper(T26.tecnicoasignado),'Á','A'),'É','E'),'Í','I'),'Ó','O'),'Ú','U') = '32') order by sat.vlstintervencion_pendientes.codtecnico ASC,sat.vlstintervencion_pendientes.fechainicio ASC,sat.vlstintervencion_pendientes.horainicio ASC,T28.razon ASC,sat.vlstintervencion_pendientes.codincidencia ASC''')
    ##RECORRIENDO LOS DATOS
    datos = cadv.fetchall()
    output = ""
    for dato in datos:
        ##VOLCAR INFORMACION
        cticket.execute('''INSERT INTO tickets (
            codincidencia,
            tecnicoasignado,
            fecha,
            hora,
            referencia,
            modelo,
            codcliente,
            razon,
            problema)
            VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s''',
            (dato[0], dato[1], dato[5], dato[6], dato[7], dato[8], dato[9], dato[10], dato[14]))

    ##CERRAR CONEXIONES
    cadv.commit()
    cticket.commit()
    cadv.close()
    cticket.close()
```

Me falta este error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\TI1\Desktop\SINF\main.py", line 21, in sync_bbdd
    port = "5432",
  File "C:\Users\TI1\Desktop\SINF\virt\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect       
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError
```

Gracias

Comment: Generalmente, las aplicaciones no abren dos conexiones a bases distintas. Cuando se requiere acceso a una tabla en otra base de datos entonces en la base de datos de la aplicación se definen sinónimos o dvlinks o views hacia esas tablas, de modo tal que desde una sola conexión puedas ver las tablas de otra base de datos como si estuviera en tu db. Si tu

Comment: En todo caso abres una conexión pasas yodo a un dataframe y cierras la conexión. Luego abres la segunda y utilizas el datafframe para actualizar la segunda base.

Comment: ¿Es posible hacerlo con dos motores de base de datos diferentes? por ejemplo, POSTGRESL y MYSQL

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que uses pgdump. Está incluido con la instalación de postgresql y te permite volcar todos los datos de una base de datos postgres a un archivo, para luego restaurarlos. En bash podrías hacer algo así:

```
pg_dump -h localhost -U postgresl adverp > adverp.sql
cat adverp.sql | psql -h localhost -U postgresl sinf_tickets
```

Debes tener en cuenta que la base de datos sinf_tickets debe existir previamente, y que el usuario postgresl debe tener permsisos sobre ella. Ambos comandos te solicitarán la contraseña.